# Was it necessary for me to make my own sorting function?

Tags: python, sorting

I made a script in python that takes the input:name grade and stores them in an array like `students = [['name', 93.3]]` it takes a list of multiple students sorts them in ascending order and then prints them sorted. I'm a beginner at programming so I can't help feeling there's an easier way to do this or maybe I'm wrong and this is pretty much how it's done.

```
def SortList(aList):
    myList = list(aList)
    secSmallest = []
    #sorting
    for x in range(len(myList)-1):
        for _ in range(len(myList)-1):
            if myList[x][1] > myList[x+1][1]:
                smaller = myList[x+1][1]
                smallerName = myList[x+1][0]
                larger = myList[x][1]
                largerName = myList[x][0]
                myList[x][1] = smaller
                myList[x][0] = smallerName
                myList[x+1][1] = larger
                myList[x+1][0] = largerName
                element = x
                for _ in range(x):
                    if myList[element][1] < myList[element-1][1]:
                        smaller = myList[element][1]
                        smallerName = myList[element][0]
                        larger = myList[element-1][1]
                        largerName = myList[element-1][0]
                        myList[element][1] = larger
                        myList[element][0] = largerName
                        myList[element-1][1] = smaller
                        myList[element-1][0] = smallerName
                        element -= 1
                    else:
                        break
            else:
                break
    return myList
```

Comment: Generally, to sort custom datatypes, make a `class`, then implement a compare function, then use the `sorted` method, which would take a list of those class objects. Or since this is Python, use lambdas.

Comment: The easiest way to do it is `sort(aList)`. Although it's still worth implementing a sorting algorithm. Good practice and very educational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def SortList(aList):
    return sorted(aList, key=lambda el: el[1])
```

A good introduction to Python's sorting is here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 4):

You can use the sort-method:

```
students = [['name', 93.3]]
students.sort(key=lambda element: element[1]) # sort by score ascending
```

Comment: Worth mentioning, `reverse=True` will do descending

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do that in python is to use python's own sorting function.

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted_list = sorted(aList, key=itemgetter(1))
```

However it's good for your own benefit that you tried to implement the sort yourself, although it seems that your algorithm could use some polish. Try reading about [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) if you want to try and implement some easy sorting algorithm yourself.